# Was any UN Security Council vote triple-vetoed?

Tags: united-nations, veto, unsc

It's reasonably well known that some UN Security Council resolutions were vetoed by two permanent members. Recent examples include Russia and China jointly vetoing resolutions [on Syria](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/mar/01/russia-and-china-veto-un-resolution-to-impose-sanctions-on-syria) and [on Venezuela](https://www.dw.com/cda/en/venezuela-us-resolution-vetoed-by-russia-china-at-un-security-council/a-47734238), but there are older precedents in this respect, e.g. the very first US veto (on Southern Rhodesia) [was jointed](https://www.nytimes.com/1970/03/18/archives/us-in-first-veto-in-un-backs-britain-on-rhodesia-first-veto-by-us.html) with that of the UK.

But were any UN resolutions (or other matters) that were triple-vetoed by the permanent members?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wikipedia has the [complete list of vetoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vetoed_United_Nations_Security_Council_resolutions).

France, UK, US joined force:

- twice in 1989 regarding Panama and Libya;
- in 1986 regarding Libya;
- 4 times in 1981 regarding Namibia;
- 3 times in 1977 regarding South Africa;
- in 1976 regarding Namibia;
- in 1975 regarding Namibia;
- in 1974 regarding South Africa.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out it happened at least twice in relation to Namibia and respectively South Africa, as a  1975 [report](http://africanactivist.msu.edu/document_metadata.php?objectid=32-130-1E43) says

> The mailing says the USA, Britain and France today exercised their veto power in the United Nations Security Council in behalf of South Africa and against an assertion of UN rights in Namibia and of the rights of the Namibian people to their freedom and independence; the big three teamed together again - as they did on 30 October 1974 when they thwarted South Africa's expulsion from the UN - to cast the second triple veto in the history of the world body; the three Western permanent members rejected a mandatory arms embargo

A [2014 article](https://www.e-ir.info/2014/03/27/the-veto-problems-and-prospects/) mentions there were 13 triple vetoes and 16 double ones, without further details.